# Can Yoda pilot a starfighter?

Tags: star-wars

In a trailer for Kinect Star Wars, I saw Yoda driving a Jungle Speeder and that got me wondering. Can and has Yoda ever piloted a starfighter?

During the Clone Wars, it seems plausible that they could commission a small-sized green Jedi starfighter. Is their any indication that he has piloting experience?

[image]

Comment: If we can make cars for midgets, they can make starfighters for Yoda. :)

Comment: Size matters not.....

Comment: Yes, he can.  He just has to sit on a copy of the Coruscant phone book to reach the controls.

Comment: I'm pretty certain Yoda could pilot a starfighter while still on the ground...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

In [Yoda: Dark Rendezvous](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda%3a_Dark_Rendezvous), a Yoda impersonator is shown on the Holonet piloting a starfighter, as part of a plan to hide Yoda's  real location.

Which implies that Yoda could pilot one.

Comment: Hmm. The fact that people weren't freaked out that his *impersonator* could pilot a starfighter isn't necessarily proof that Yoda himself could fly one.

Comment: Not a Proof but strong evidence. Otherwise the decoy wouldn't be worth a dime.

Comment: @flq - If I saw a realistic video of a celebrity piloting a helicopter, I'd probably assume they could pilot a helicopter. That doesn't in itself mean they can.

Answer (score 18):

Within the Clone Wars TV series, we see Yoda flying a starfighter on several occasions;

[image: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-sIzhO33xi7M/UxsFUpLpB3I/AAAAAAAAFVU/djVGlzBiL64/s1600/yoda-starfighter-clone-wars-612.jpg]

He also has his own Clone Wars '[Jedi Attack Fighter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Star-Wars-Attack-fighter-Figures/dp/B00ABUGP30)' toy (complete with **FIRING MISSILE LAUNCHERS!**) although I can't remember seeing him pilot it in show;

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the clone wars tv series he pilots a ship resembling a star fighter but with a ball cockpit and is shorter than other star fighters

Comment: Which episode? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @dvk - Screenshot above in my answer. It's shown very briefly in the Season 6 trailer but I've no idea what episode.